# Android Spinner select Characteristics

Tags: android, list, spinner

I got a very annoying problem here and I hope you can help me.

I have a List of Plants (Self defined Class). These Plants got a Name, an ID and some characteristics. The characteristics are saved in Strings.
F.e. `Characteristic1` is the size of a plant, `characteristic2` is the design of the leafs and so on..

I have some Spinners now, and in each of these Spinners a Selection of one characteristic should be available (Spinner1 got all characteristics from the variable characteristics1 from all plants, ...)
The goal is that I can use these Spinners to give the User the Plants, which suits to the User's Selection of the characteristics.

Any ideas how I can implement that in a non-spaghetti way? I'm a bit new to programming so I could really need your help.

I Hope I explained it well, it's quite hard for me explaining it in my second language.

My Code:

Plant - Class

```
private int pd_id;
private String pd_plantname;
private String pd_longinfo;
private String pd_infochar1;
private String pd_infochar2;
private String pd_infochar3;
private String pd_infochar4;
private String pd_infochar5;
```

Image-Class

```
private int i_id;
private int i_p_id;
private String i_path;
private Calendar i_date;
```

In my Activity i got a List of Images and a List of Plants.
To Fill a Spinner with the characteristics i use this Code.

```
ArrayList<String> sInfo1 = new ArrayList<String>();
while (i < plantlist.size()) {
    sInfo1.add(plantlist.get(i).getPd_infochar1());
    i++;
}
ArrayAdapter<String> spInfo2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sInfo1);
        spArt.setTag(1);
        spArt.setAdapter(spInfo1);

spAlter.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener(spAlter));
```

I got this 5 times for 5 spinners. Now to the OnItemSelectedListener

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if (sp.getTag() == spAlter.getTag()) {
                int i2 = 0;
                while (i2 < plantlist.size()) {
                    if (plantlist.get(i2).getPd_infochar1()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase((String) sp.getSelectedItem())) {
                    }
                    else{
                        if(((String) sp.getSelectedItem()).equalsIgnoreCase("--Bitte auswählen--")){

                        }
                        else{
                            int pid = plantlist.get(i2).getPd_id();
                            plantlist.remove(i2);
                            ArrayList<Image> localIlist = getImageListFromPlantID(pid);
                            int x = 0;

                            while (x < localIlist.size()){
                                Toast.makeText(entscheidungsbaum.this, localIlist.get(x).getI_path(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                imageList.remove(localIlist.get(x));

                                x++;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    i2++;
                }
            }
```

So I delete for each characteristic which is wrong the images from the imagelist (which is the source for a gridview).

Firstly, this works not very well, I get some wrong images...
Secondly, that code is very bad, I know that. Can you help me find a better way to adapt the imagelist to the Spinner Selection?

Comment: mhm, what happened here? There was an answer already and now its gone? :(

Comment: That answer wasn't an answer, so it was deleted. Your question is too vague to be answered here. You will need to post some code and indicate what you have tried and we can help you solve specific problems with your code. Nobody here is going to write the code for you. We all have day jobs.

Comment: I really dont wanna that anyone of you write the Code for me, you can believe me that. Its just that i dont know how to do it and want some help how i could do it, not a finished code ;)
No prob that the answer was deleted, but the comments where interesting, would be cool if they were saved ;) anyway i try to get more in detail ill edit my post ;)